# background-position not working when orientation landscape

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using an SVG as a background image with `background-size:cover`. The following picture shows the current situation:

[image]

I would like to place the red rectangle always on the left of the actual content of my website. I tried to use media queries to control the background position, unfortunately it doesn't work in the media query with `orientation: landscape`. However, the green color is correctly applied. (Note that I used both Chrome and Firefox dev tools to test media queries, the result is identical).

Is it possible to correct this behavior? If not, what strategy would you suggest to achieve my goal?

html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="home-page">
    <div class="hp-content">
        <div class="welcome">Welcome to</div>
        <div class="site">
            <div>My</div>
            <div>Super Duper Website</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag">
            <span>Tag 1</span>
            <span>Tag 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.css:

```
#home-page {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("test2.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    perspective: 500px;
}

.hp-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.welcome {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.site {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .site {
        color: blue;
    }
    
    #home-page {
        background-position-x: 45%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .site {
        color: green;
    }
    
    #home-page {
        background-position-x: 30%;
    }
}
```

test2.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   style="isolation:isolate"
   viewBox="0 0 5333 3000"
   width="5333pt"
   height="3000pt"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg897"
   sodipodi:docname="test2.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata901">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="983"
     id="namedview899"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.199"
     inkscape:cx="3555.3333"
     inkscape:cy="2000"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="24"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg897" />
  <defs
     id="defs889">
    <clipPath
       id="_clipPath_T82IRtemKzxS24oK6qpn3KBJWLS4PYGV">
      <rect
         width="5333"
         height="3000"
         id="rect886" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g
     clip-path="url(#_clipPath_T82IRtemKzxS24oK6qpn3KBJWLS4PYGV)"
     id="g895">
    <rect
       x="1561"
       y="400"
       width="405"
       height="2309"
       transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"
       fill="rgb(255,0,0)"
       id="rect891" />
    <path
       d=" M 0 1080 L 0 3000 L 5333 3000 L 5333 1827 L 1849 2605 L 0 1080 Z "
       fill="rgb(0,132,35)"
       vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
       stroke-width="1"
       stroke="rgb(0,0,0)"
       stroke-linejoin="miter"
       stroke-linecap="square"
       stroke-miterlimit="3"
       id="path893" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to have an image background that's correctly positions in a number of viewports and orientations. A possible strategy is to use CSS shapes to accomplish the effect, where you have greater control over placement. This is a possible solution, where individual elements can be quickly modified.

```css
            body {
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
            }

            #home-page {
                position: relative;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                perspective: 500px;
            }

            .hp-content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .welcome {
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            .site {
                font-size: 40px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #triangle-bottom-left {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-bottom: 38vw solid green;
                border-right: 80vh solid transparent;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            #triangle-bottom-right {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-bottom: 25vw solid green;
                border-left: 135vh solid transparent;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }

            #vertical-column-element {
                width: 4em;
                height: 35vh;
                background-color: red;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 20vw;
            }

            @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
                .site {
                    color: blue;
                }

                #triangle-bottom-left {
                    border-bottom: 38vw solid green;
                    border-right: 80vh solid transparent;
                }

                #triangle-bottom-right {
                    border-bottom: 25vw solid green;
                    border-left: 135vh solid transparent;
                }

                #vertical-column-element {
                    width: 6em;
                    height: 66vh;
                    left: 10vw;
                }
                
            }
            @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
                .site {
                    color: green;
                }

                #triangle-bottom-left {
                  border-bottom: 38vw solid green;
                  border-right: 80vh solid transparent;
                }

                #triangle-bottom-right {
                  border-bottom: 25vw solid green;
                  border-left: 135vh solid transparent;
                } 

                #vertical-column-element {
                    width: 6em;
                    height: 75vh;
                    left: 15vw;
                }
                
            }
            @media (min-width: 1025px) and (orientation: landscape) {
                .site {
                    color: orange;
                }

                #triangle-bottom-left {
                  border-bottom: 38vw solid green;
                  border-right: 80vh solid transparent;
                }

                #triangle-bottom-right {
                  border-bottom: 25vw solid green;
                  border-left: 135vh solid transparent;
                } 

                #vertical-column-element {
                    width: 6em;
                    height: 75vh;
                    left: 15vw;
                }

            }
```

```html
    <div id="home-page">
        <div class="hp-content">
            <div class="welcome">Welcome to</div>
            <div class="site">
                <div>My</div>
                <div>Super Duper Website</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tag">
                <span>Tag 1</span>
                <span>Tag 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="vertical-column-element"></div>
            <div id="triangle-bottom-left"></div>
            <div id="triangle-bottom-right"></div>
    </div>
```